# Feature activate via UI but does not show in the Libraries and Lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

1. I am really hating SharePoint as there are hardly any good/concrete documentation.
2. I developed custom List "MainCatalog" with few columns (not site columns).
3. Create features and elements with MOSS feature builder at Site collection level so scope="site"
4. installed via stsadm
5. activated via UI "went to site collection website", Site Setting > Site collection Feature (and saw my custom list "MainCatalog") and was able to activate.
6. then went to "mySiteCollection > Site Settings > Site Libraries and Lists "
7. My list is showing
8. But it shows in the "mySiteCollection > Create > Custom Lists > "MainCatalog"
9. I guess it's showing there as a template...

But my intention is to deploy this list from development to test environment. EXTREMELY STRESSED. I AM ON THIS FOR LAST 8 DAYS.....

Answer (score 2):

So you've successfully created, deployed and activated the Feature which provides the *template* for the list, as you say.   You can then create an *instance* of the list manually, using the template, or you can have the Feature automatically provision an instance when activated.  To do so, add the following to your Elements.xml (or whatever you have named it):

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<ListTemplate Name="MainCatalog" Type="12345" BaseType="0" SecurityBits="11" DisplayName="Main Catalog" Description="Create a Main Catalog list instance" Image="/_layouts/images/itgen.gif" RootWebOnly="FALSE" OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"/>
<ListInstance Id="MainCatalog" TemplateType="12345" Title="Main Catalog" Url="Lists/MainCatalog" Description="Main Catalog list"></ListInstance>
```

Then deploy this Feature to your test environment.